# Error converting data type varchar to bigint

Tags: c#, sql-server

When i use this string as a sql command-string compiler gives me no error:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE StudentNo='" + T_No.Text + "'";
```

But, if i use this string (includes '%' character) it says "**Error converting data type varchar to bigint**":

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE StudentNo='%" + T_No.Text + "%'";
```

What should i change in order to use '%' in my statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE convert(nvarchar,StudentNo) LIKE '%" + T_No.Text + "%'";
```

Note, however, that this is inefficient.

Comment: No need to convert to string. `like` does that automatically and why `nvarchar` rather than `varchar` if the string only contains digits anyway?

Comment: It works, thank you very much. But what's the logic behind all of this?

Comment: @Martin given the question, I thought that an explicit cast was more useful in making @gcx understand the issue here. But you're right about nvarchar, it's superfluous.

Comment: @gcx 1) you need to use the LIKE operator when dealing with patterns (that is, '%' in your case. 2) you cannot compare different types. in your first example the query parser is smart enough to automatically convert your right-side string to a number, but it cannot do that in your second example because of the '%' chars.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following page.

http://web.archive.org/web/20150519072547/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-search-for-special-characters-e-g-in-sql-server.html

The % sign has a special meaning in SQL.